# Read And Update JSON File Using nsJSON Plugin (NSIS)

Tags: nsis, nsjsonserialization, electron-packager

I am trying to update one data on JSON file using nsJson Plugin.

My JSON data on File

```
{   "header_left_lebel": "LEFT LEBEL",
    "header_center_label": "CENTER LEBEL",
    "base_path": "E:\Workspace\my-demo-app"
}
```

I want to edit the base path during installation of the application.

My Code to Read and Update the Value

```
Section "Installation Section"
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR" 

    GetFullPathName $0 ..
    StrCpy $installationPath "$0\${applicationName}";This Holds the installation path

    nsJSON::Set /file `$installationPath/config/settings.json`
    nsJSON::Set `base_path` /value `"$installationPath"`
    nsJSON::Serialize /file `$installationPath/config/settings.json`

   WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd
```

The above code updates the JSON file but it only keeps **base_path**

I want to keep all the data and only to update **base_path**

Any help or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works correctly for me when using NSIS v3.04 and JSON plug-in v1.1.1.0 (November 2017):

```
Unicode True

!macro DumpTxtFile file
Push "${file}"
Call DumpTxtFile 
!macroend
Function DumpTxtFile 
Exch $0
Push $1
FileOpen $0 $0 r
loop:
    ClearErrors
    FileRead $0 $1
    IfErrors done
    DetailPrint $1
    Goto loop
done:
FileClose $0
Pop $1
Pop $0
FunctionEnd

!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
FileOpen $0 "$temp\NSIStest.json" w
FileWrite $0 '{   "header_left_lebel": "LEFT LEBEL",$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '    "header_center_label": "CENTER LEBEL",$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '    "base_path": "E:\Workspace\my-demo-app"$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '}'
FileClose $0
!insertmacro DumpTxtFile "$temp\NSIStest.json"

Var /Global installationPath
StrCpy $installationPath "c:\dummy\path"

ClearErrors
nsJSON::Set /file `$temp\NSIStest.json`
nsJSON::Set `base_path` /value `"$installationPath"`
nsJSON::Serialize /format /file `$temp\NSIStest.json`
${If} ${Errors}
  Abort "Unable to update JSON file!"
${EndIf}

!insertmacro DumpTxtFile "$temp\NSIStest.json"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I have some permission issue on installing the app on "C" drive. That's why update was not working. I fixed that by using 'AccessControl::GrantOnFile". Your Code is also working. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to add better error handling to the current code, I'll try to do that tonight.

Comment: `${StrRep} '$0' '$installationPath' '\' '\\'` for replace single backslash "\" with double backslashes "\\". https://nsis.sourceforge.io/StrRep